# update-initramfs causes segmentation fault

Tags: apt, raspberrypi, initramfs

I was trying to install `lsscsi` on my Raspberry Pi 4, running Ubuntu 20.04.  I don't have a detailed log of what happened, but it got to the end where it says "processing triggers", then it said something about "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img", and then it started printing out "segmentation fault (core dumped)" repeatedly.

Now any time I try to do anything with `apt` it does something very similar, for example:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1058-raspi
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
<repeated>
```

It seems to be trying to finish off that failed install. I don't know what to do.  Need some help.

**Edit: Another thing I've tried:**

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1058-raspi
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
<repeated>
```